# Why use the Less parent selector (&) at the beginning of a line?

Tags: less

I understand what the parent selector does but I'm not sure I understand the syntax when it's at the beginning of a line. For example, this can be found in semantic-ui-less. For which use case would you wrap the import statement into `& {}`

```
/* Global */
& { @import "definitions/globals/reset"; }
& { @import "definitions/globals/site"; }
```

Why using this syntax instead of simply stacking the imports? What would the previous syntax do more over this one:

```
/* Global */
@import "definitions/globals/reset";
@import "definitions/globals/site";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Imports within `... {}` get their own scope (for more details see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-73839112 and https://github.com/less/less-docs/issues/21).

Comment: @seven-phases-max, thanks for the answer! I had the feeling that the curly braces were for scope containment but it's the & at the front that puzzled me. I guess that the & is just part of the syntax and doesn't do anything more. If you post it as an answer, I could make it the official answer.